Corresponding docker command of `podman run --replace`
In podman, use --replace to replace existing container
According to podman-run — Podman documentation

--replace
If another container with the same name already exists, replace and remove it. The default is false.

What is the corresponding command in docker?
Not find in docker run | Docker Docs

There's no equivalent docker run option; the documentation you link to would show it if there was.
It should be more or less equivalent to explicitly stop and delete the existing container
docker stop "$CONTAINER_NAME" || true
docker rm "$CONTAINER_NAME" || true
docker run --name "$CONTAINER_NAME" ...

